# Pass by ref and typecast at the same time

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do this in C#?

```
private void Caller()
{
  MyControl c = new MyControl();
  Callee(ref c);                       //Here I want to cast c as Control and pass by ref
}

private void Callee(ref Control c)
{

}
```

---

In the generics example, how does it infer T = MyControl? Can you please explain? I am a newbie to generics

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd question whether you *need* `ref` - it seems unusual; that would mean you intend to re-assign the variable inside the method? (different to changing properties of the passed instance).

For `ref`, it must be an exact match; you could use:

```
Control tmp = c;
Callee(ref tmp);
c = (MyControl) tmp;
```

Alternatively, consider generics:

```
private void Callee<T>(ref T c) where T : Control
{ ... }
```

Then you can use `Callee(ref c)` and it will infer `T = MyControl`

(updated re comment)

In the generic example, we declare `Callee` as a generic method "of T", where T is *at least* a `Control`. This "at least" ensures that we still have access to all the members of `Control` inside the method (since any subclass of `Control` still has those members).

Generics act a bit like templates (but not quite). The **caller** gets to specify the T when calling the method. So the caller could use `Callee<Control>(...)`, which would compare to calling your existing `Callee(ref Control c)`. Or they could use `Callee<MyControl>(...)`, which is like calling `Callee(ref MyControl c)` - in both cases the `T` gets substituted throughout the method.

However, the C# compiler is intelligent enough that often you don't need to tell it the bit in angle brackets; it can see that you are passing a `MyControl`, so it will assume (unless you tell it otherwise) that it should use `T = MyControl` - this is called generic type inference. The point here is that it makes it easy to use `ref` with subclasses of the data.

Comment: Aren't objects inherently passed by reference?

Comment: @Austin - well, to be exact: all arguments are (by default) passed by value, but for reference-types, both copies still point to the same underlying object. But I know what you mean ;-p And hence my "First, I'd question whether you need ref"

Comment: Cool... I thought you might be spilling my C# cup all over the floor!

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible and there's a good reason for that. Imagine that you change c in Callee and assign another descendent of Control to it that is NOT an instance of MyControl.